# How to remote debug managed code with symbol servers

Tags: .net, debugging, symbols, remote-debugging

I'm aware of the differences of remote debugging native / managed / mixed applications as it is explained [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/monicaboris/archive/2004/02/16/74520.aspx).

My question is: is possible to remote debug an application using a symbol server to load symbols? I've tried it without success. Looks like VS does not try to look at the symbol server.